# $L^\infty$ boundedness for solution of elliptic PDE with Neumann BC

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations

On a bounded smooth domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ consider the equation $$-\Delta u + ku = f$$ $$\partial_\nu u = 0$$where $k>0$ is a constant and $f \in L^2(\Omega)$.

We know that $u \in H^2(\Omega)$.

Is it possible that $u$ has the regularity $u \in L^\infty(\Omega)$?

If $f \in L^\infty(\Omega)$, then this is true (see eg http://www.math.tu-berlin.winkert.de/publications/papers/PreprintNODEA2010.pdf). However under the $L^2$ assumption only I am not sure. I had thought there would be $L^2-L^\infty$ smoothing effect?

Comment: How is this question "off topic"?

Comment: One reason for "off topic" seems to be: "This question is missing context or other details". This is clearly the case for this question.

Comment: @gerw Please see edit

Comment: This paper http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=AIF_1965__15_1_189_0 by Stampacchia might be of help (see Section 4). The techniques should go through for Neumann BC as well, as long as the bilinear form is coercive on $H^1$.